# Auto Sorting Sheets Based on Values

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm creating a rudimentary inventory tracking system. I first want anything with a value greater than zero to appear at the top of the sheet (current inventory), and then I want all of those rows to be "sub-sorted" alphabetically. I successfully auto-sorted my sheet by two separate columns using the script in this link:

https://www.idiotinside.com/2018/06/08/sort-multiple-columns-google-sheets-apps-script/

However, I want one of the columns to be sorted by a value (greater than zero). I've been searching the stacks and haven't found anything related. I searched the script library, as well, but new to this, so may not have searched properly.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The idea of stackoverflow is that you put some effort in trying to write a code yourself and ask for help at the point where you get stuck.

Comment: I attempted to insert the script from the link I shared, but it was the wrong format, I guess. And that is also something I didn't know how to write properly.